# Validate Paypal Smart Buttons from Java Backend

Tags: java, angular, typescript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I´m using a Java Backend and i implemented Paypal Smart Buttons into my Angular Frontend. It is obvious that they are not that safe, because you could manipulate the price.

I want to request my Backend where i take the price stored in my Database, which is not static btw.
And toggle the Paypal window from there, with the validated price.
Does anyone have an example? Or is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order'. You can use the [Checkout-Java-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK) for the routes' API calls to PayPal, or your own HTTP function. Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Such createOrder/onApprove functions that call your server with `fetch` can be used in framework-specific code (in place of the client-side actions.order.create() / .capture() , which you will not be using). There are [samples for Angular and others here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/single-page-app/#link-addthecode).

Comment: Im having trouble adapting this to system. Is it enough if i copy the paypal folder from the sdk and add it to may backend structure?

And i am no sure how the paypal client method should look like :(

Comment: The usage guide is at https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Java-SDK#usage .  The client JS should look like the createOrder and onApprove functions in https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , surrounded by whatever framework-specific code you're using (as desired). Otherwise it's just that HTML/JS which can work anywhere.